# Не могу подключится к Django приложению, расположенному на AWS Ubuntu EC2

Tags: python, django, amazon-web-services

Я запускаю Django приложение на AWS EC2(Ubuntu) t2.micro. Я установил все нужные модули, создал PostgreSQL базу данных, скачал свой проект с s3 и сделал все миграции. Теперь когда я запускаю команду `python manage.py runserver 172.31.27.208:8000` я не могу подключиться к этому адресу через браузер, получаю ошибку ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT.

`python manage.py runserver 172.31.27.208:8000` возвращает:

```
System check identified no issues (0 silenced).
January 30, 2020 - 11:10:59
Django version 3.0.2, using settings 
'project_test.settings'
Starting development server at 
http://172.31.27.208:8000/
Quit the server with CONTROL-C.
```

Так что я полагаю что сервер запускается корректно.

Я использую private ip адрес из aws ec2 console для этого инстанса, который, я проверил, совпадает с адресом, который возвращает команда `ifconfig`.

TCP открыт на порте 8000 в AWS security_group inbound rules.

[image: Вот скрин секьюрити группы:]

Я также проверил `netstat -lan | grep :8000` после того как запустил Django runserver, возвращает:

```
tcp        0      0 172.31.27.208:8000      0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN
```

То есть на нужный порт биндится нужный ip адрес.

Попробовал сделать curl на адрес на котором запускал runserver, с того же хоста на котором я его запустил запросы проходят, ни с других удаленных серверов, ни с моего локального компьютера - нет. Это наталкивает меня на мысль что что-то не так с файрволами. Файрвол самой системы проверил, там все открыто, значит по идее остается только файрвол на AWS.

Я просматривал похожие проблемы и все перечисленные в решения уже правильны в моем случае. Так что я не имею понятия, в чем проблема. Могу предоставить вам больше информации, если вам что-то нужно. Буду благодарен за любую помощь. Спасибо.

Comment: А вместо `python manage.py runserver 172.31.27.208:8000` пробовали: `python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000` ?

Comment: Да, то же самое.

Comment: а скрин правил можете добавить ? в security_group

Comment: а так-же проверте может фаервол еще в самой ОС

Comment: @EvgeniiIzhboldin, добавил, пробовал курлами с того же сервера обратится приложению, все работает, но ни с каких других серверов - нет. Как будто aws блокирует все ip адреса, но с чем это может быть связано, я не понимаю.

Comment: А где у Вас там порт 8000 в правилах ? я вижу только 80, 5432 и 22

Comment: Amazon автоматом добавляет 80 для tcp, насколько я понимаю это рейндж всех портов типа 80хх.

Comment: Нет. Это только 80 порт. Порт 8000 Вам самому нужно добавить. То что там Port Range, это потому, что там можно указать несколько портов, но в данном случае у Вас там один порт.

Comment: Но Вам достаточно просто добавить новое правило с портом tcp 8000

Comment: @EvgeniiIzhboldin, спасибо большое за идею с портами, на aws нужно было добавить custom TCP rule для конкретного порта 8000 или 8080 и тогда при запуске runserver на private_ip:8000 приложение правильно форвардится и доступно в браузере по public_ip:8000.

Comment: Большое спасибо всем за помощь!